# Can humans be "beneficial" to each other?

Tags: word-choice

> I could be beneficial to you if you hire me.

Is that an idiomatic English sentence? Can we use *beneficial* for humans?

Comment: Yes, that is grammatical and understandable, but see answers for other possibly better phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would say, "My competence will benefit your company". The sentence you asked sounds a bit strange to me. I usually hear people say "A benefits B", such as "The policy benefits thousands of people", or "B benefits from A", as "Thousands of people benefit from the policy".

Hope my answer is helpful :)